# Stating CONSTANT values in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, constants, state

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to state somewhere some CONSTANT values that is accessible by all classes in the application. I will use mentioned constants *mostly* for "global" validation purposes but I am considering to use those also for implement an authorization system.

Where and how I have to state these constants? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont u create a .rb file in

```
 config/initilizers directory
```

and define your constants there.

PS:-- you need to restart your server to access those variables.

Comment: Jain - I have to add that '.rb' file, and then? Is it auto-loaded on re-inizializing the application or I have to state that somewhere?

Comment: Jain - Your previous comment was deleted so your answer can not be accepted as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

One place for this in Rails 3 is `config/application.rb` (module *YourAppName*, class Application) along with some of the Rails configuration lines. Some constants may also fit very well with your model classes, so you might want to consider this on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use an initializer or a simple yml file, loaded at startup - look at EnvYAML recipe at http://railswizard.org/ for example.